# Git Extensions has pending changes that aren't my own?

Tags: git, version-control, github, msysgit, git-extensions

This question might be a long shot because I still cannot reliably duplicate the issue but it has happened to several of my coworkers on many occasions and it still baffles me.

Occasionally Git Extensions (on Windows 7) will show pending changes in their working directory that are not their own after they commit and do a push. The push fails because it says they have pending changes, despite the fact that they just barely committed all their pending changes before the push. This is the point when I get called over. Upon examination of the changes they are changes that were made by another committer and pushed up to origin. A couple times the changes have even been changes that were done by me.

Devloper A (we'll call Bob) goes ahead and makes a series of changes to his repository. Bob then commits those changes and pushes the commit up to origin.

Developer B (w'll call Fred) also makes some changes and commits them to his repository. Fred then tries to push those changes up to origin. At this point I would expect Fred to get an error saying that his repository is behind origin by 1 commit and tell him to do a pull first. However, the error he gets says the push failed because he has pending changes in his working directory. When Fred looks at the pending changes he sees that all the changes are actually the changes made in Bob's commit.

When Fred commits those changes as if they were his own then all seems well. Nothing breaks from it but it's extremely bizarre when it happens. I have yet to see what happens if we try to undo the pending changes because I am afraid the changes will essentially be reverted if we did that.

Has anyone else ever experienced this odd behavior with Git or Git Extensions?

### Update

I found an instance in our project history where this happened. Both commits have the same exact changes to the same number of files, but the commits are done by two different developers.

Here is Bob's original commit:
[image]
And here is Fred's wonky commit:
[image]
Edit: Just to clarify, Fred meant to type "push changes" as the commit message because it was the act of trying to push (not pull) that caused the mysterious pending changes to appear.

Comment: I think that absent a specific series of steps to reproduce this problem it's going to keep looking like operator error...ideally using the command line tools, so that we can see any odd output or errors.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. It's just an intermittent thing that's driving me crazy!

Comment: I went so far as to create a fake repo and 3 fake users on Github. I have then wired up 3 virtual machines so I could experiment with different scenarios. I cannot duplicate it. But sure enough, the moment I forget about it, it happens again! If it was one user then I'd think it was operator error, but it's happened to 3 different coworkers several times and continues to happen now and then.

Comment: See my update. Maybe the history can say something about the issue.

Comment: What is the "pull changes" commit? a pull should result in an automatic merge commit like `merge origin/master`

Comment: He meant to type "push changes". The pull changes commit is the duplicate commit. Fred didn't know what to type in the comment box since he was essentially committing the same thing Bob already Committed so he just typed "pull changes" since they were changes he magically got during the push. Like I said, he meant "push changes" because it was the push, not the pull, that caused this weird issue. I added a clarifying note to the question.

Comment: I was thinking that the branching lines have something to do with it. If you notice the original commit occurs on a branch line away from master. Mysteriously the duplicate commit occurs on the main branch line ***before*** Bob's branch line converges with the original line. Though, because of Git's distributed nature I don't fully understand what those lines represent, especially considering that I don't think he actually created a whole new branch for one single commit. Although it's not impossible.

Comment: Is the .git directory being shared between multiple people?

Comment: @JoePhilllips What do you mean? Like on a single machine? No, each machine only has one developer that ever uses it.

Comment: Is the "abort" button being used in GitEx? The whole process totally breaks down when that happens and files have to be reset, etc.

Comment: No abort button is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you copy and post the error message, when it happens next time? Content of Help -> Git command log would be also helpful. Does Fred have checked Auto pull on rejected option (FormPush -> Advanced options)?

Comment: There is no error message when it happens. Just some mysterious pending changes. I will look for the Git log next time it occurs. Fred does not have Auto pull on rejected checked.

Also, this would have been better as a comment ;)

Comment: You wrote 'However, the error he gets says the push failed because he has pending changes in his working directory'. I meant about this error. It is realy weird, that git push failed because of changes in working direcroty.

Comment: +1, my mistake. I will be sure to tell my devs not to close the error when it happens next time. By the time they call me over they have already closed it and begun examining the supposed pending changes. I will also try to duplicate the act of pushing with pending changes to verify that it does indeed throw a fit if there are uncommitted changes.